# Python Dataframes: Data Column Being Read in As Row Index Mistakenly and reset_index() Produces Wrong Output

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, row

I currently have a dataframe called `df` and it's sample output is below:

[image]

I believe the `Name` column is being read in as the row index which I don't want.  My desired dataframe would look like this:

[image]

As such, I tried the following code:

```
df = df.reset_index()
```

But the output is wrong ... it looks like this:

[image]

How can I get my desired df output?

Comment: `Name` looks like the column name. Try `df.rename_axis(columns=None, index='Name').reset_index()`

Comment: can you explain conceptually why that code works please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dataframe:

```
>>> df
Name    Score    Age Address
Abbott  value  value   value
Aaron   value  value   value
Johnny  value  value   value
Paul    value  value   value
Sam     value  value   value
```

Check row and column indexes:

```
>>> df.index
Index(['Abbott', 'Aaron', 'Johnny', 'Paul', 'Sam'], dtype='object')

>>> df.columns
Index(['Score', 'Age', 'Address'], dtype='object', name='Name')
```

As you can see, `Name` is not the index name but the name of the data columns:

```
>>> print(df.index.name)
None

>>> print(df.columns.named)
Name
```

Now swap the names:

```
>>> df.index.name, df.columns.name = df.columns.name, df.index.name

>>> print(df.index.name)
Name

>>> print(df.columns.name)
None

>>> df
        Score    Age Address
Name                           # <- name of data index
Abbott  value  value   value
Aaron   value  value   value
Johnny  value  value   value
Paul    value  value   value
Sam     value  value   value

>>> df.reset_index()
     Name  Score    Age Address
0  Abbott  value  value   value
1   Aaron  value  value   value
2  Johnny  value  value   value
3    Paul  value  value   value
4     Sam  value  value   value
```

To fix it, @QuangHoang suggested you:

```
>>> df.rename_axis(columns=None, index='Name').reset_index()
     Name  Score    Age Address
0  Abbott  value  value   value
1   Aaron  value  value   value
2  Johnny  value  value   value
3    Paul  value  value   value
4     Sam  value  value   value
```